# How to fix the `@JvmStatic` in interface usage error in IDEA when using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin multiplatform project and the newest version of IDEA started to complain about `@JvmStatic` usages in interfaces:

[image]

What's weird is that I added the necessary config to my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
kotlin {

    jvm {
        withJava()
        jvmTarget(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
    }

    // ...
}
```

and I also set it up in IDEA here:

[image]

and here:

[image]

and I also added the compiler parameter as IDEA suggested. What am I doing wrong?

If I build the project from the command line I get a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with multiplatform projects Gradle IDEA import: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43074. In this particular case it is acceptable to suppress the error until the bug is fixed:

```
@Suppress("JVM_STATIC_IN_INTERFACE_1_6") // remove when KT-43074 is fixed
fun empty() = ...
```